# Why do we have $ P(\sqrt{X_1^2+\dots+X_d^2}\ge t)\le \sum_{j=1}^dP(|X_j|\ge t/\sqrt{d})$?

Tags: probability, statistics

For a sequence of random variables $X_1, \dots, X_d$, why do we have
$$
P(\sqrt{X_1^2+\dots+X_d^2}\ge t)\le \sum_{j=1}^dP(|X_j|\ge t/\sqrt{d}) \, (*)?
$$

I guess I need to prove

$$
P(\sqrt{X_1^2+\dots+X_d^2}\ge t)\le P(\bigcup_{j=1}^n\{\sqrt{d}|X_j|\ge t\})
$$

If we define $\max_j X_j=\max_j\{X_1, \dots, X_d\}$, then
$$
P(\sqrt{X_1^2+\dots+X_d^2}\ge t)\le P(\sqrt{d}\max_j|X_j|\ge t)
$$
But how to get (*)?

Comment: You modified your question several times to change the meaning each. Don't do that, better delete and re-ask the question.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot add $\sqrt{d}$, this is a typo. Otherwise, this will be no meaningful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The result is false.** Let me first prove that the reverse is true. In other words,
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \geq \mathbf{P} \left( \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^p \{|X_i| > t\} \right).
$$
This follows directly from monotonicity of the probability measure since if any of the $|X_i| > t$ then also $\sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t.$

**What is true is the following,** by triangle inequality, $\sqrt{a_1^2 + \ldots + a_p^2} \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^p |a_i|,$ so if $\sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} \geq t$ then $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^p |X_i| \geq t$ and we obtain the following inequality
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \leq \mathbf{P} \left( \sum\limits_{i = 1}^p \{|X_i| > t\} \right).
$$

**OP wonders if
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^p \mathbf{P} (|X_i| > t).
$$**
The answer is no. Consider $p = 2$ and $X_1, X_2$ independent Bernoulli of parameter $p = \dfrac{1}{2},$ say. Then,
$$
\mathbf{P} \left(\sqrt{X_1^2 + X_2^2} > 1 \right) = \mathbf{P}(X_1 + X_2 > 1) = P(X_1 = X_2 = 1) = p^2,
$$
however, $\mathbf{P}(X_1 > 1) = \mathbf{P}(X_2 > 1) = 0.$

**OP changed the question (again, yikes!) to**
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^p \mathbf{P} \left( |X_i| > \frac{t}{\sqrt{p}} \right).
$$
This is true. If $X_{(p)}$ denotes the largest amongst the $X_j,$ then $\sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t$ implies that $\sqrt{p} |X_{(p)}| > t$ so
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \leq \mathbf{P} \left( |X_{(p)}| > \frac{t}{\sqrt{p}} \right).
$$
The event $|X_{(p)}| > c$ means that the largest (and therefore, at least one of) the $X_j$ is greater than $c,$ so
$$
\mathbf{P} \left( \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_p^2} > t \right) \leq \mathbf{P} \left( \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^p \left\{|X_i| > \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{p}}\right\} \right).
$$
The inequality follows from subadditivity. QED

Comment: In fact, $\sqrt{\sum a_i^2} \leq \sum |a_i|$ is easier to see by just noticing both sides are positive so the inequality is true if and only if the square of it is true and that reduces to show $0 \leq \sum_{i \neq j} |a_i| |a_j|,$ which is obviously true.

Comment: I somehow misread the union inside the probability as a sum, in fact, as written, you original question is rather rare. I guess you meant $P\left(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^p \{|X_i| > t\}\right)$ and intuition tells me this should be _false._

Comment: In fact, it is quite obvious that if some $|X_i| > t$ then $\sqrt{\sum X_i^2} > t,$ so the first inequality should be reversed. In other words, your original question is going to be false in general, except then the two sides have equal probability. That would entail some restriction on the support of the variables.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot $\sqrt{d}$... That should be $ P(\sqrt{X_1^2+\dots+X_d^2}\ge t)\le \sum_{j=1}^dP(|X_j|\ge t/\sqrt{d}) $